# Python Export Program to PDF using Latex format

Tags: python, pdf, export, latex, pdflatex

I have a GUI program in Python which calculates graphs of certain functions. These functions are mathematical like say, cos(theta) etc. At present I save the graphs of these functions and compile them to PDF in Latex and write down the equation manually in Latex.

But now I wish to simplify this process by creating a template in Latex that arranges, The Function Name, Graph, Equation and Table and complies them to a single PDF format with just a click.

Can this be done? And how do I do it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. generate a Latex `file.tex` with a Python script

   f= open("file.tex", 'w')

   f.write('\documentclass[12pt]{article}\n')

   f.write('\usepackage{multicol}\n')

   f.write('\n\begin{document}\n\n')

   ...

   f.write('\end{document}')

   f.close()
2. run `pdflatex` on the LaTex file from the Python script as a subprocess

   subprocess.call('latex file.tex')

As an alternative to 1. you can generate a LaTex template and just substitute the variable stuff using Python regular expressions and string substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a couple of programs to do this sort of thing. I find it
works well to have a template like this:

```
latex_template = r"""
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, letterpaper, margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{txfonts}
...
$preamble
...
$data

\end{document}
""".lstrip()
```

And then use `string.Template` and its `substitute` method to plop the
variable parts into the template.

Answer (score 0):

Although matplotlib (for example) can output PDF for not only graphs, but also render LaTeX equations, and even can produce tables, I suspect that what you want is [pyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/), which is a package to allow you to import separately created PDFs, page-by-page, and concatenate them into a new PDF. The excellent little utility pdfshuffler uses just this approach, in a (python-based) GUI.

On the other hand, if you insist on creating a single LaTeX file to pass to pdflatex, then you can achieve this using string manipulation. Something like:

```
text = open('template.tex')
complete = text.format(name,graph,equation,table)
open('temp.tex','w').write(complete)
subprocess.call('pdflatex temp')
```

Where `template.tex` contains suitable placeholders, `{0}`, etc., to place the latex code referred to in the format method.